# Web scraping olx

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I just got into web scraping and decided to create a scraper for car prices as my first project. I encountered a problem pretty quickly where when i printed the soup object it just printed a few lines saying 'Service Unavailable' and that 'The server is temporarily unable to service my request' . Why does that happen and how do i fix it, Thanks in advance !

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/en/vehicles/cars-for-sale/' 
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print (soup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `User-Agent` HTTP header to get correct response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/en/vehicles/cars-for-sale/' 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print (soup)
```

Prints:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta content="H1XIF2PCYRBVJS6NaAD2pcbbm2oqGGCj7KenRQGyVGI" name="google-site-verification"/>
<meta content="5A57304F35F5718EAD39F1A8E1EE8D3C" name="msvalidate.01"/>

...and so on.
```